# Extending an existing xsd schema

Tags: xsd

I would like to do following thing:

```
<a xmlns="http://example.com/general"
   xmlns:ext1="http://example.com/extension1"
   xmlns:ext2="http://example.com/extension2">
    <b name="asdf">
        <ext1:test>HELLO</ext1:test>
        <ext2:test>HELLO</ext2:test>
    </b>
 </a>
```

Basically i try to create a basic schema which can be extended by any user with an additional schema file. The extension schema files defines that there have to be the element "ext1:test" and "ext2:test".

I have tried it with redefine but then i have to replace the namespace general with the extension xsd - see below. That works very fine for one extension but then the user cannot include multiple extensions.

```
<!-- general.xsd -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/general"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://example.com/general">

    <xs:complexType name="aType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="bType" name="b"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="bType">
        <xs:group ref="bGroup"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:group name="bGroup">
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:group>

    <xs:element name="a" type="aType"/>
</xs:schema>

<!-- extension-base.xsd -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/extension"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://example.com/extension">
    <xs:group name="extendedBGroup">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="test" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
</xs:schema>

<!-- extension.xsd -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/general"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:ext="http://example.com/extension"
           xmlns="http://example.com/general">
    <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/extension" schemaLocation="extension-base.xsd"/>

    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="general.xsd">
        <xs:group name="bGroup">
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:group ref="bGroup"/>
                <xs:group ref="ext:extendedBGroup"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:group>
    </xs:redefine>
</xs:schema>

<!-- test.xml -->
<a xmlns="http://example.com/general"
   xmlns:ext="http://example.com/extension"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/general extension.xsd">
    <b>
        <ext:test>HELLO</ext:test>
    </b>
</a>
```

Has anyone an idea how i can achieve the first example?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The "thing" you need to use it for can change how to solve your issue.

Comment: i want to be able to extend the general xsd file with more than one other xsd file at once. it is hard to explain (: do you know what i mean?

Comment: Well, that is what you "want", but what are you going to use it for? Because your choice might be to simply create a single a single XSD without extensions containing user modifications and your base/or to use XSLT to create a specific result or allow multiple XSD files instead of extensions etc

Comment: the resulting file will contain metadata which can be extended by an other component. so one single xsd is not a "good" solution for that. i have found the "xs:any" but then the extension has no possibility to validate it.